# Query to get all reservations that either begin or end within a time range?

Tags: mysql, sql

I believe this is a quite trivial query(I did search SO and Google but came to nothing), SQL isn't definitely my strong point, and I've been on a coffee rampage for the past hours...

I'm working on a simple booking system.

I have a reservations table like the one bellow:

```
id | room_id | checkin_date  | checkout_date |
---+---------+---------------+---------------+
1  |    12   | 2012-10-12    |  2013-01-14   |
2  |    9    | 2012-12-08    |  2013-01-10   | 
3  |    4    | 2012-12-19    |  2012-12-26   | 
4  |    6    | 2012-11-12    |  2012-12-30   |  
5  |    3    | 2012-12-11    |  2012-01-11   |
```

How can I get all the reservations that ***either end or begin*** inside a certain interval(the data will then be used to populate an availability calendar).

Sorry about not posting my own Sql, but all of my many attempts have been futile(and shamefully bad).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from reservations 
where checkin_date between ? and ?
or checkout_date between ? and ?
```

You need to supply the start and end dates in the placeholders, for example

```
select * from reservations 
where checkin_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-66'
or checkout_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-66'
```

Comment: Jesus Christ that was fast-..you'd have to see the mess of AND's & OR's I made. Serves me right for using an ORM, and not learning proper SQL. I didn't even remember of the between operator... Thanks.